# php imap retrieve only the oldest email

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

Goodmorning,

I'm trying to retrieve only the oldest email that matches my imap_search.
So I need to get rid of the foreach loop.
I've already tried just removing it, but that didn't work.

code:

```
<?php
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = '**';
$password = '**';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails, voeg hier extra search opties in bijv: SUBJECT "wat er in het onderwerp moet staan" From "email.van.herkomst@example.com" */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN SUBJECT "Task has succeeded"');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* for every email... */
    if($emails as $email_number) {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* output the email header information */
        $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
        $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
        $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
        $output.= '</div>';

        /* output the email body */
        $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
    }
    echo $output;
}

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

Kind regards,
Lars Kaptein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since imap_search returns an array, you can just use regular array functions:

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN SUBJECT "Task has succeeded"');
$last = array_pop($emails);
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$last,0);
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$last,2);
$output = '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
$output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
$output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
$output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
$output.= '</div>';
$output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: i still had to use `$output = '';`

Comment: but thnx this really helped a lot :D

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the code so that the first $output has just `=`.